# In a sequence of bernoulli trials, what is the probability that exactly x trials will occur before rth success?

Tags: probability

> In a sequence of independent identical trials with two possible outcomes on each trial, Success or Failure, and with $P(S) = p$, what is the probability π that exactly x trials will occur
> before the $r$th success?

This might be more of a linguistic problem, but my intepretation of the question is that the total trials conducted is x+1, i.e. x for what happens before the rth success and x+1 being the rth. Hence P(rth success) = $C^x_{r-1} p^r (1-p)^{x-r+1}$.

However the provided solution states that:

> The probability of observing r − 1 successes out of the first x − 1 trials is P(X = r − 1),
> with X ∼ Bin(x − 1, p)

Thus

> P(rth success) = $C^{x-1}_{r-1} p^r (1-p)^{x-r}$.

Hence, my question - why should the latter be the correct intepretation?

Comment: I think you're right that this is a problem of language. The phrase "exactly $x$ trials will occur before the $r$th success" is ambiguous. I would likely want to interpret it the same as you did, but the person who wrote the problem (or at least the solution) appears to think that a trial is something you do before you observe the outcome of that trial. Or maybe they think "before" means what I would mean by "at or before".

Comment: Indeed.  The solution given is for "the probability for $x$ trials *until* the $r^{th}$ success,"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just from reading the statement, I imagine that "exactly $x$ trials will occur before the $r$th success" means that the $r$th success occurs concomitantly with the $x$th trial. It is just the way that these problems are stated. I guess there could be confusion about the word before, leading you to want to create $x$ trials and then $r$th success on the $x+1$st trial. Instead, think of it as a $x$ trials occurring and then in an infinitesimal moment after the $x$th trial the $r$th success registers.